# R seq cant match value in sequence

Tags: r, numbers, match, seq

I have a very basic question. I define a simple sequence:

```
numbers=seq(0.001,0.5,0.001)
```

now I want to know which element of this sequence has value 0.01, I tried this:

```
which(numbers==0.01)
```

but I just get

```
integer(0)
```

asking for the 10th elment gives me

```
numbers[10]
[1] 0.01
```

But

```
numbers[10]==0.01 
[1] FALSE
```

Can it have something to do with the places behind the decimal point?
How can I get the element (here:10), that matches a certain value? (here: 0.1)?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `which(round(numbers,3) == .01)` This link [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) May help explain why

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I couldn't figure this out for the longest time! Rounding works.